# How to make Discussions visible at Recent Discussions?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, discussion-board

I made a number of tiles with discussions underneath. There is already some activity. How do I link it to Recent Discussions on the main page? There is nothing to see now. Not even when I click on Recent Discussions.

P.s.,

If this question has already been asked, my apologies. I've been searching for a while but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

By design, there is no way to display the latest reply/activity on the **Recent** view in the **Discussion Board**

However, the **Recent** view dispalys the "**Latest reply by**". If the discussion has not reply, the “**Last reply by**” will not show up.

[image]

Comment: There are some replies but they also dont show up. Do I have to link the discussions to Recent?

Comment: Hi, Matthew. Can you tell me what you said activities specifically refers to what? Activity is Reply? Have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, by activity I mean replies in a few discussions. They don't show up in Recent. You also have a nice day! =)

Comment: @Matthew, Can you please mark few reply as "Best Reply" and see if those are reflected

Comment: Hi, Matthew. By design, there is no way to display the latest reply on the Recent view in the Discussion Board.